# How to retrieve environment variables in project on dev .net 6

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, environment-variables, .net-6.0

I am learning about environment variables and how to use them on dev and in production on azure. So far I have some setting values in my `appsettings.json` file within the values section. I want to get this setting out. I tried

```
string value = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TestValue");
```

doesn't return anything.

Here are my settings:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "Values": {
    "TestValue": "HelloWorld",
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

I want to set the variable in my appsettings and then call `getvariables` function to get them is that possible. The reason I want to do this is because I don't want to check in my `appsettings.json` file on git, instead when I deploy to production, I want to add the settings myself manually on Azure using the variables.

Comment: Because your json is setting file, not a container for environment variables.

Comment: [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58685686/how-to-set-environment-variables-from-appsettings-json-for-net-core-console-app)

Answer (score 0):

- Create a class with name `Details` and declare variables

```cs
  public class Details
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

- In `Program.cs` add the below code

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
Details myDetails = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Values").Get<Details>();
var app = builder.Build();
```

***Output:***

[image]